# from_request mismatched types

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I am learning rust and I am trying to run the cookies/session example from rocket repo (https://github.com/rwf2/Rocket/blob/master/examples/cookies/src/session.rs)

```
use rocket::http::Status;
use rocket::outcome::IntoOutcome;
use rocket::request::{self, FromRequest, Request};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct User(usize);

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl<'r> FromRequest<'r> for User {
    type Error = std::convert::Infallible;

    async fn from_request(request: &'r Request<'_>) -> request::Outcome<User, Self::Error> {
        request
            .cookies()
            .get_private("user_id")
            .and_then(|cookie| cookie.value().parse().ok())
            .map(User)
            .or_forward(Status::Unauthorized)
    }
}
```

but I am getting `mismatched types` error

```
|             .or_forward(Status::Unauthorized)
|              ---------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found `Status`
|              |
|              arguments to this method are incorrect
```

If I replace `.or_forward(Status::Unauthorized)` with `.or_forward(())` then it compiles, but I loose the status.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're compiling code for `rocket v0.5.0-rc4` and up with an old version ([`<=0.5.0-rc3`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.3/rocket/request/type.Outcome.html)) of it as dependency, in your `Cargo.toml` replace the line resembling this:

```ini
[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "0.4" }
```

with this:

```ini
[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "0.5", features = ["secrets"] }
```

and maybe `cargo update` as well.

[rustexplorer](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/qoksrw)

Comment: That was it! Although I was using =0.5.0-rc.3. Thanks a lot for a super quick response.